# How to: PHP $_POST vars to AJAX $.ajax post call on a JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Ok, this could seem a little bit confusing, but the idea is next:

1. Normal PHP page which receives POST calls, and considering those vars acts in some or other ways. No problem, normal thing.
2. Some of the aspects which are loaded in this page (info blocks which get some big data from database), independently of POST vars and whatever, take long time to load, so I've decided to dynamically load them, instead of loading everything on loading page time. This means that in the beginning page was rendering and taking so long and right now, it renders fasts and shows some "loading..." blocks with spinning icon on them. Those blocks are basically "$.ajax" calls via POST, once $(document).ready();. Ok? No probe here too. All ok.
3. **And now the problem:** some of those blocks shows one or other info accordingly to $_POST received vars. Once this wasn't AJAX, everything worked right. But now, the received from server processed page (which already used the POST vars) to the client, makes new post calls to particular scripts and those scripts doesn't have the PHP POST needed vars.
   Obviously you could say do something like:

```
$.ajax{
...
data: <?php ..............?>
...
}
```

but I can't, as this is a JS file, none PHP with embedded JS on it.

So the question is:

What can I do?
Which would be a good implementation for this particular solution?

It is not a design fault, as it works nice if it doesn't uses ajax. This is not a previous ajax call that can be made on request call. It is basically loading some page parts dynamically on serving time!

So what?

Thank everyone so much, and I hope you can help me whit it!

PS: **I've came up with an idea**, and it is basically, before load the main JS file, to create a petite snippet which basically transforms $_POST array to a JS object with all the bars in it. But even being it useful and probably great, I guess it basically fucks up security and obfuscation a lot!

Comment: Your idea in the "PS" is already on the right track, you need to make the POST data available to your ajax calls. If you need to "hide" the real data, you might want to save the session data and just send kind of a token/key. By using that token, you can recreate the session data during the ajax call.

Comment: Hi Paul, so you and Steve down here, agreed with the session storing thing. You say "recreate the session data during the ajax call", I understand that you mean use the stored post to session data on the PHP script called by the AJAX call, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous options. As you mention, you can pass the data to the client via inline js or dsata attributes, then post the data back in the ajax calls.

This will work fine, but if you have security concerns, then the alternative is to persist the data serverside, and change the php scripts retrieval method:

```
//main.php - the file that initially loads:
session_start();
$_SESSION['post']=$_POST;
//rest of script

//sidebar.php - the file called by ajax
session_start();
if(!$_POST){
    if(isset($_SESSION['post']){
        $_POST = $_SESSION['post'];
    }
}
//rest of script
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks. Is yours a good solution to the problem? Cause I like it but I don't know if it is somehow "redundant"... as long as after use the post data stored to session, it will prevail all the script long... and I don't like it much, as it is only useful on a particular screen...

Comment: @Lightworker Well i don't know the specifics of your code, so this is just an example - you could clear the session variable after use, or generate a unique token in the initial load and pass that to the ajax requests - thats really up to your specific requirements

Comment: @Steve shows a valid way to store the POST data. And as he mentions, it really depends on your application how to go on with that. If the particular data is only relevant for a designated part, you could indicate that by using `$_SESSION['screenID']` instead of using `$_SESSION['post']` and only get this data if the user is on that page again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've finally came about:

- Changed the "main.js" file to "main.php" file.
- On header, changed the  to require_once ".../js/main.php"
  Now you have all the code block on header, but somehow I guess it's exactly the same?
- Now I can put PHP code on """JS""" main file. And right now I can do something like:

[image]

```
var data = [];
//Controlled parameters which sure I'll have and always will add manually.
data.push({ name: "ajax", value: action }); //add more parameters...
data.push({ name: "section", value: section });

//Those "others" POST parameters which can vary depending on the request call.
<?php foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v){ ?>
    data.push({ name: "<?php echo $k;?>", value: "<?php echo $v;?>" });
<?php } ?>

...

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "?a="+action,
    //data: { ajax: action, section: section },
    data: $.param(data),
    timeout: 8000 //8 seconds max.
}).done(function( data ) {

...
```

And that's it!

I've started by creating an object in JS on every view which played with this concept of forwarding POST data. But it was "unmaintainable".

Then I thought that could be good to create a JS snipet after main.js inclusion on header precisely with this "object creation POST data", as all the calls are going to be made on $(document).ready(); time, so sure it will be accessible. You know: if it exists use it if not... blah!

But the I thought that it is not necessary to create a POST object in JS all the time, as long as sometimes probably big data is going to be on server-side, so do not want to put it on client to. You delivery this "post" thing to the object and with time, you forget on this and start to put things on POST no-one should see and it happens that you have'em absolutely visible on JS!

So it seem that your proposed options (SESSIONING the POST via "post" var on session array or by ID screening) should be the most secure in this idea of reusing the info only on server side, but I've found it somehow... "tedious to mantain" too.

So I've finally came up with this idea. And as this is only happening on load time AJAX loaded blocks, this JS data is going to happen on very concret situations and parameters are going to be pretty small. Nothing to worry about I guess.

**So questions come to my mind:**

1. You like it? Is a good implementation or you think its a better approach to use the "session" thing?
2. Security compromising?
3. To add a script on head with src="..." so dinamically add the JS file to webpage, is the same in terms of time and used resources to add the code directly to head tag (which happens when you do a require_once for a PHP file which contains dinamized JS code)?